# Sensible way to report errors from cron jobs

Tags: error-handling

I have several jobs that run nightly. Generally they work but from time to time they fail. What's the best way for them to report failure?

The way that seems obvious to me is to send email. I have several google accounts and would like to use one for this purpose.

However, I cannot after several attempts, get my head around how to do this while keeping my google account secure. I appreciate that I need to use OAuth2, which I understand at a design level but I can't work out the implementation details.

- I can't find a simple command-line utility that would allow, say

  send *recipient-email-address* --subject *error in overnight job* --attachment *log file*
- I'd be quite happy to roll my own command-line program, preferably using C++ and Qt, but I can't work out the details.

In these circumstances, it usually turns out that the reason I can't find out how to do what I want is because I'm trying to do something silly.

Any suggestions would be appreciated immensely.

[Apologies. I'm not sure I've tagged this properly as I feel it's more about error reporting than handling, but... Do please re-tag it if there's a better tag that I've overlooked.]

Comment: @KilianForth. D'oh! Thanks for correcting my typo. *blush*

Answer (score 3):

Email is fine, but I wouldn't do it from the cron job.

The first thing I'd do is establish appropriate logging in the cron job. Have it write to a log file in an appropriate format. Have consistency in verbosity and how log messages are presented. At the same time, I'd also establish log rotation policies to archive and ultimately delete these logs.

Then, I'd set up some kind of monitoring tool. There are plenty of tools that are designed to ingest log files along with other system and application performance metrics. Set one of these up and get all of your logs from your different cron jobs and the system as a whole off of the server into a centralized repository.

If you need to set up alerting, the monitoring tool can either do that or integrate with actual alerting tools. These can send emails, Slack messages, texts, make phone calls. Whatever is necessary when the system enters an unstable state. Or you may just monitor the tool without any external alerting.

Comment: Not really the answer I was hoping for, but thanks. For the record, the jobs run on my home system and are configured to write stdout and stderr to different files, which are overwritten the following night. I'd like to mail myself the error file if it's not zero-length. I will research free system monitoring tools.

Comment: @nurdglaw Ah, that wasn't clear. You can probably still apply log rotation to the log files, which would help to keep old logs and eventually delete them. If you have the right stuff going to the error log, then perhaps the cronjob emailing the log file(s) at the end would be good as well. Most of our questions here aren't about things running at home, but large scale complex systems.

Comment: No problem, and sorry I wasn't clear the first time around. From the short time I've spent looking at them, monitoring tools seem to be a) overkill, and b) non-trivial. Mind you, writing a command-line email tool seems to be non-trivial too :-/

Comment: @nurdglaw I'm guessing it's Linux?

Comment: Windows 7 Home, actually. Sorry I mentioned cron. Some of the jobs are run via scheduled tasks but that suddenly stopped letting me add new jobs (read as "I've forgotten how to set up new scheduled jobs") and some are processes run from a cygwin window with a command line ending "&" that wake up daily and don't exit. The scheduled task run with the stdout/stderr mechanism described above. I'd like to detect and email errors in the other as and if they occur.